# Allow SVN commit with existing PreCommit hook warnings

Tags: php, svn, coding-style, phpunit, pre-commit-hook

I am using SVN precommit hooks to validate my code standard (PSR2) before being able to commit. This works perfectly with just one exception. My unit test (PHPUnit) files exist of my bootstrap class existing of all static unit test functions, but also enables error messages above the bootstrap class definition.

The PSR2 standard will give a warning when trying to commit this, because you cannot have code that is not in a class or function in a file that contains a class definition.

Does anyone have either a way to exclude this error in my codesniffer or a way to make my code valid (without putting the code to enable my error messages in each static function of the bootstrap class)?

Here's the file:

```
<?php
namespace AlbumTest;

use Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory;
use Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use RuntimeException;

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
chdir(__DIR__);

class Bootstrap
{
    protected static $serviceManager;
    protected static $config;
    protected static $bootstrap;

    public static function init()
    {
        // Load the user-defined test configuration file, if it exists; otherwise, load
        if (is_readable(__DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php')) {
            $testConfig = include __DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php';
        } else {
            $testConfig = include __DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php.dist';
        }

        $zf2ModulePaths = array();

        if (isset($testConfig['module_listener_options']['module_paths'])) {
            $modulePaths = $testConfig['module_listener_options']['module_paths'];
            foreach ($modulePaths as $modulePath) {
                if (($path = static::findParentPath($modulePath)) ) {
                    $zf2ModulePaths[] = $path;
                }
            }
        }

        $zf2ModulePaths  = implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $zf2ModulePaths) . PATH_SEPARATOR;
        $zf2ModulePaths .= getenv('ZF2_MODULES_TEST_PATHS') ?: (defined('ZF2_MODULES_TEST_PATHS')
                                                            ? ZF2_MODULES_TEST_PATHS : '');

        static::initAutoloader();

        // use ModuleManager to load this module and it's dependencies
        $baseConfig = array(
            'module_listener_options' => array(
                'module_paths' => explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $zf2ModulePaths),
            ),
        );

        $config = ArrayUtils::merge($baseConfig, $testConfig);

        $serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig());
        $serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $config);
        $serviceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();

        static::$serviceManager = $serviceManager;
        static::$config = $config;
    }

    public static function getServiceManager()
    {
        return static::$serviceManager;
    }

    public static function getConfig()
    {
        return static::$config;
    }

    protected static function initAutoloader()
    {
        $vendorPath = static::findParentPath('vendor');

        if (is_readable($vendorPath . '/autoload.php')) {
            $loader = include $vendorPath . '/autoload.php';
        } else {
            $zf2Path = getenv('ZF2_PATH') ?: (defined('ZF2_PATH')
                                          ? ZF2_PATH : (is_dir($vendorPath . '/ZF2/library')
                                          ? $vendorPath . '/ZF2/library' : false));

            if (!$zf2Path) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                    'Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.'
                );
            }

            include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';

        }

        AutoloaderFactory::factory(
            array(
                'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                    'autoregister_zf' => true,
                    'namespaces' => array(
                        __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                    ),
                ),
            )
        );
    }

    protected static function findParentPath($path)
    {
        $dir = __DIR__;
        $previousDir = '.';
        while (!is_dir($dir . '/' . $path)) {
            $dir = dirname($dir);
            if ($previousDir === $dir) {
                return false;
            }
            $previousDir = $dir;
        }
        return $dir . '/' . $path;
    }
}

Bootstrap::init();
```

Answer (score 0):

How does your precommit-hook look like? Could you just remove the first few lines dynamically before sending the to the Codesniffer?
Another solution would be to set the error_reporting in the init of your bootstrap

Comment: My pre-commit hook simply checks my code for PSR-2 rules when committing. Removing lines would be strange, but please elaborate on this idea...

Putting the error reporting in my init would work for that function, but I would have to copy it to all the other functions as well. And that is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: How does your Code Sniffer get the data? Is it possible to read from stdin, so removing the first files could be done on the fly, without generating temporary files?